# update and set multiple fields with same case statement

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-update, case

I want to be able to set values for two different fields with different values, which satisfy the same case statement.

Eg.

```
DECLARE @RATE1 AS FLOAT
DECLARE @RATE2 AS FLOAT


UPDATE TABLE1
SET CATEGORY = CASE WHEN DATE >= '16 JAN 2014' THEN 'NEW'
```

But at the same time I want to also SET @RATE1 = 0.001

Then

```
WHEN DATE < '16 JAN 2014' THEN 'OLD'
END
```

But at the same time I want to also SET @RATE2 = 0.002

is this somehow possible?

Comment: what these variables `@RATE1` and `@RATE2` has to do with your update statement ???

Comment: The two variables are determined by the same criteria as the update statement, so was wondering if there was a way to also set them at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE TABLE1
SET CATEGORY = CASE WHEN DATE >= '16 JAN 2014' THEN 'NEW'
                    WHEN DATE < '16 JAN 2014' THEN 'OLD' 
               END
```

For setting values to the variable you will need a separate statement something like this

```
   IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE1 WHERE DATE >= '16 JAN 2014')
    BEGIN
      SET @RATE1 = 0.001;
    END 
  ELSE
    BEGIN
      SET @RATE2 = 0.002;
    END
```

Assuming your DATE is a VARCHAR field and it has Date stored in DD MMM YYY format. not a good choice of datatype though for storing date data.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I was hoping that there was a way of setting both variable and field without having to repeat the criteria set again.

Comment: since these are two different operation they will be executed separately you can make the variable assignment statement a bit simpler see my update